# pip command not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

In installed Python 3.4 using Homebrew on my Mac OSX Mavericks

When I do which python3, I get

```
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

On checking which python I get

```
/usr/bin/python
```

which is the system installed version of Python

I intend to install virtualenv and thus ran pip install virtualenv
But I get

```
-bash: pip: command not found
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have `pip3.4` or `pip3` found?

Comment: @alecxe how do I find them?

Comment: At least, just run them and see if any errors would show up.

Comment: Do you have PIP installed? (probably not) http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest making a system installation of `pip`, `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper`. Since `pip` is not found, run `sudo easy_install pip` to get it. I would then set up your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` to activate the `virtualenvwrapper.sh` automatically.

Comment: But I checked the installation log of homebrew and I'm pretty sure pip was installed.

Comment: So what's the result of `which pip3`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

> pip3 install virtualenv

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem since I found out that I need to reinstall `pip` in my `env` again. try this in your `env`:

`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`

then

`python get-pip.py`